# Force Majeure (2014): significance of scene in the fog

Tags: plot-explanation, force-majeure

What is the significance of the scene in the fog near the end of *Force Majeure* (2014)?

Answer (score 1):

From an [interview with Ruben Östlund, the director](http://www.bbook.com/film/force-majeure/):

> *You mentioned the final, foggy ski run as a “group therapy.” Did you
>   see that scene as a desperate way to restore order in the family?*
>
> Yes, I see it as a group therapy ski run. It’s Ebba that wants to try
>   to restore the family and wants to push to make Tomas the male leader
>   of the group and the hero.
>
> *So the children can feel at ease, Ebba can feel protected, and Tomas
>   can feel like a man and they can continue lying to themselves forever.*
>
> I love the moment when he says, “We made it, we made it.” In a
>   Hollywood movie we would cut at that moment, but instead we have to
>   see their everyday life continue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I find the director's explanation appalling really. The husband goes through the fog to save his wife, so that she "can feel protected". All the while, the children are left alone and it looks like they will lose _both_ their parents. I'm sure they didn't "feel at ease". Amazing film, but awful protagonists.